# Google chart x-axis labels truncated

Tags: google-visualization

Problem is that when I set my x-axis labels vertical they gets truncated, tried to set more height -> then chart changes size but labels are still truncated.
Is there a way/hack to set x-axis labels to not truncate on overflow.

Also there is strange behavior some of x-axis labels has some padding 
-> I put red line below x-axis labels and there u can see that labels has different start positions

Thanks.

ColumnChart properties:

```
var options = {
                      title: 'title',
                      strictFirstColumnType: true,
                      lineWidth: 1,
                      isStacked: true,
                      legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'left', textStyle: { color: 'black', fontSize: 15, italic: false, bold: true }, maxLines: 5 },
                      vAxes: { 1: { title: 'y1TitleText'e,  titleTextStyle: { italic: false, bold: true }, minValue:0, gridlines: { count: 6 } } },
                      hAxis: {slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 90, title: 'titleText'},
                      fontSize: 15,
                      colors: colors
                  };
```

Diagram output :

[Output image](http://oi46.tinypic.com/2cqxrwl.jpg)

Comment: It'd be nice to have the data to test with, otherwise I can only recommend that you play around with the [`chartArea`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) option to see if that fixes it (set the chart height to 50% and see if it still cuts off the text, then adjust until it works properly).